# How i can set the height of black overlay in css that all other things goes hidden?

Tags: html, css

i have a div who have class black_overlay. i want to set them to full on the page. in my code it's only goes to 1500px.

the problem is that
if page have less height then 1500 then they goes unusually  bigger 
if page have more height then their is no benifit to use it because  i want to do this for full page.

how i can do this using css

```
#black_overlay 
{
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; left: 0; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 1500px; 
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: .8; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=80); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-height` instead of `height` as in given demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/42wTM/

Or Use `height: 100%` instead of using a fixed height

Comment: Add `min-height: as you need` & `max-height: as you need` & `height: auto` in your current style sheet.

Comment: in this case nothing happen i just want to hide full document.

Comment: I didn't understand? What you want to hide?

Answer (score 0):

The same as you did for your width:

```
height: 100%;
```